# Spring RestTemplate consume XML

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb

I am using Spring's RestTemplate to consume an API that returns XML. I'm having some problems working out how to map the XML response to a POJO.

An example of the XML being consumed is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ABRPayloadSearchResults xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearch/">
  <request>
    <identifierSearchRequest>
      <authenticationGUID>08914fce-7c0f-4aa1-9b25-d31fbe5bcf78</authenticationGUID>
      <identifierType>ABN</identifierType>
      <identifierValue>33051775556</identifierValue>
      <history>N</history>
    </identifierSearchRequest>
  </request>
  <response>
    <usageStatement>The Registrar of the ABR monitors the quality of the information available on this website and updates the information regularly. However, neither the Registrar of the ABR nor the Commonwealth guarantee that the information available through this service (including search results) is accurate, up to date, complete or accept any liability arising from the use of or reliance upon this site.</usageStatement>
    <dateRegisterLastUpdated>2016-03-21</dateRegisterLastUpdated>
    <dateTimeRetrieved>2016-03-21T09:19:43.8712423+11:00</dateTimeRetrieved>
    <businessEntity201408>
      <recordLastUpdatedDate>2016-02-05</recordLastUpdatedDate>
      <ABN>
        <identifierValue>33051775556</identifierValue>
        <isCurrentIndicator>Y</isCurrentIndicator>
        <replacedFrom>0001-01-01</replacedFrom>
      </ABN>
      <entityStatus>
        <entityStatusCode>Active</entityStatusCode>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
        <effectiveTo>0001-01-01</effectiveTo>
      </entityStatus>
      <ASICNumber>051775556</ASICNumber>
      <entityType>
        <entityTypeCode>PUB</entityTypeCode>
        <entityDescription>Australian Public Company</entityDescription>
      </entityType>
      <goodsAndServicesTax>
        <effectiveFrom>2000-07-01</effectiveFrom>
        <effectiveTo>0001-01-01</effectiveTo>
      </goodsAndServicesTax>
      <mainName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA CORPORATION LIMITED</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2000-01-20</effectiveFrom>
      </mainName>
      <mainTradingName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2000-01-20</effectiveFrom>
      </mainTradingName>
      <otherTradingName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA CORPORATION LIMITED</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2000-09-12</effectiveFrom>
      </otherTradingName>
      <otherTradingName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA CORPORATION LIMITED</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2000-07-21</effectiveFrom>
      </otherTradingName>
      <otherTradingName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2000-04-26</effectiveFrom>
      </otherTradingName>
      <mainBusinessPhysicalAddress>
        <stateCode>VIC</stateCode>
        <postcode>3000</postcode>
        <effectiveFrom>2014-09-18</effectiveFrom>
        <effectiveTo>0001-01-01</effectiveTo>
      </mainBusinessPhysicalAddress>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>Anywhere Healthcare</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2015-05-19</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>Belong Broadband</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2015-01-14</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>KIT STORE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2014-11-05</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>MY HEALTH GATEWAY</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2014-10-23</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>ReadyCare Australia</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2014-08-28</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>ReadyCare Corporation</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2014-08-28</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>Medgate</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2014-08-05</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>Telstra Medgate</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2014-08-05</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA GLOBAL</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2012-06-21</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>AUTOMOTIVE ALLIANCE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2011-12-29</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>AUTOMOTIVE ALLIANCE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2011-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>AUTOMOTIVE ALLIANCE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2011-10-26</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>AUTOMOTIVE ALLIANCE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2011-10-24</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>AUTOMOTIVE ALLIANCE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2011-10-12</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>AUTOMOTIVE ALLIANCE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2011-10-07</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>AUTOMOTIVE ALLIANCE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2011-09-05</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>AUTOMOTIVE ALLIANCE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2011-09-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>T LIFE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2010-03-12</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES SERVICES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-07-18</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES SERVICES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-07-07</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES SERVICES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-06-18</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES SERVICES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-06-11</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES SERVICES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-06-10</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-02-12</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES SERVICES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-02-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES SERVICES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-02-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-01-24</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2008-01-03</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2007-12-18</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2007-12-12</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2007-12-12</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2007-12-11</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>SPECIALISED RECOVERIES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2007-12-10</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA LEARNING ACADEMY</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2007-09-06</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TRADING POST</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2005-03-21</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TRADING POST</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2005-03-11</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>NETWORKING TASMANIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2005-02-28</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TRADING POST</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2005-01-06</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>CREDITECH</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2004-11-16</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TRADING POST</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2004-11-15</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>CREDITECH</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2004-10-26</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>CREDITECH</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2004-10-25</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>CREDITECH</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2004-10-21</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>CREDITECH</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2004-10-21</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>BIGPOND MUSIC</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2003-12-05</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA LICENSED SHOP</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2003-07-08</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA SHOP</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2003-07-08</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>BIGPOND</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2003-07-02</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA LICENSED SHOP</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2003-06-18</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELECOM AUSTRALIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2003-02-21</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA'S KIDS FUND</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2002-04-08</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>THINGS THAT GO</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2002-03-04</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA BUSINESS SHOP</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2002-01-21</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>MOBILEFUN</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2001-07-04</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>CONFERLINK</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2001-05-21</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRAWHOLESALE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2001-02-07</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA COUNTRY WIDE</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2000-06-20</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TRADING POST</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>2000-05-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>CREDITECH</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>CREDITECH</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>CREDITECH</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>PHONEWATCH</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELECOM AUSTRALIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELECOM AUSTRALIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELECOM AUSTRALIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELECOM AUSTRALIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELECOM AUSTRALIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELECOM AUSTRALIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELECOM AUSTRALIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TELSTRA SHOP</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TRADING POST</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>TRADING POST</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>WHEREIS</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>YELLOW PAGES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>YELLOW PAGES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>YELLOW PAGES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>YELLOW PAGES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>YELLOW PAGES</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
      <businessName>
        <organisationName>YELLOW PAGES AUSTRALIA</organisationName>
        <effectiveFrom>1999-11-01</effectiveFrom>
      </businessName>
    </businessEntity201408>
  </response>
</ABRPayloadSearchResults>
```

The code that tries to unmarshal the XML into a POJO is

```
String queryString = "/abrxmlsearch/ABRXMLSearch.asmx/SearchByABNv201408";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(endpoint)
        .path("/abrxmlsearch/ABRXMLSearch.asmx/SearchByABNv201408")
        .queryParam("includeHistoricalDetails", "N")
        .queryParam("searchString", naturalKey)
        .queryParam("authenticationGuid", authenticationGuid)
        .build()
        .toUri();

//ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(targetUrl, String.class);
AbrPayloadSearchResults response = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, AbrPayloadSearchResults.class);
```

My POJO at the moment is

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ABRPayloadSearchResults")
public class AbrPayloadSearchResults {

    @XmlElement(name = "request", required = true)
    protected Object request;

    @XmlElement(name = "response", required = true)
    protected Object response;

}
```

I seem to be falling at the first hurdle here, because the server is complaining about the root element.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not unmarshal to [class AbrPayloadSearchResults]: unexpected element (uri:"http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearch/", local:"ABRPayloadSearchResults"). Expected elements are <{}ABRPayloadSearchResults>; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearch/", local:"ABRPayloadSearchResults"). Expected elements are <{}ABRPayloadSearchResults>

    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.readFromSource(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:143)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:280)
    at com.pegasus.apollo.hub.idprovider.impl.abr.AbrIdProvider.findByNaturalKey(AbrIdProvider.java:37)
    at com.pegasus.apollo.hub.idprovider.impl.abr.AbrIdProviderServiceE2ETest.testFindByNaturalKey(AbrIdProviderServiceE2ETest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearch/", local:"ABRPayloadSearchResults"). Expected elements are <{}ABRPayloadSearchResults>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
```

Would someone be able to help me out regarding what XML annotations I am messing up?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest using the xjc command line tool to generate the classes automatically from a schema. If you don't have a schema for your xml, there are tools out there that can generate a schema from an example xml. This tends to be a little bit more safe than writing the annotations manually.

Comment: Thanks. xjc just saved me a lot of faffing around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the appropriate namespace to your `@XmlRootElement`:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearch/", 
                name="ABRPayloadSearchResults")
public class AbrPayloadSearchResults {
```

Comment: Excellent, that fixed it. Thanks for the help